# ArrayIndexOutOfBound when passing split string into constructor parameter

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I don't what's wrong with my code. It keeps giving me `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the split line. Can someone tell me what's wrong with the split line? 
I'm reading string from a file , spliting it into two then constructing a new object with the split string in parameter to save in the memberList. 
here's my txt file

```
counter.strike@gmail.com Password
shane.atik@hotmail.com telephone
wise.man@ymail.com 123423
EOF
```

and I changed my code a bit. but that still doesn't help me with the split Line.

```
try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\memberlist.txt"));
            String inputLine; 
            while( (inputLine = br.readLine())!= null ){
                String[] split = inputLine.split(" ");    
                User newUser = new User(split[0], split[1]);
                memberList.put(key, newUser);
                key++;
        }
```

PS there is a catch clause. and here is what my text file looks like

Comment: Can you help me with why I'm getting the exception ?

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to help you without having your txt file.
The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException indicate that your split return an empty array or an array with only one result. You probably have a line in your code with no space.

Try the debbug mode of eclipse or display the content of your array to debbug it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ever considered that a line can have a string without " ". In that case you will get IndexOutOfBound exception as split[1] is non-existent.